# How to combine multiple javadoc doclets?

Tags: gradle, javadoc, plantuml, doclet

I have been working on producing a javadoc for a large project and am not sure what I am trying to do is even possible, or would require making a third doclet combining others. I have been able to successfully use the doclets `org.asciidoctor.Asciidoclet` (using asciidoc syntax for javadoc comments) and `info.leadinglight.umljavadoclet.UmlJavaDoclet` (auto-generated plantuml class and dependency diagrams), but I am not seeing how they can be combined. Reading through the javadoc documentation and google-fu has not turned up much discussion on this kind of process. I am using gradle as my build tool and the javadoc plugin.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks!